# Why does my loop stop after the first iteration?

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to loop through a dictionary of lists and return the keys of values which contain a specific integer.

For example if I loop through `{0: [3], 1: [3], 2: [4, 0], 3: [1], 4: [1, 0, 2, 3]}` with `v = 4`, it should return `[2]`.

However, my code seems to only consider the very first key-value pair and I do not understand why. It works if the integer is in the first key-value pair and not in any others. Here is the function I made:

```
def whence(g, v):
    # Your code here
    lov = []
    count = 0 
    for key, value in g.items(): 
        if v in value:
            lov.append(count)
        count += 1
        print(lov)
        return lov
```

Comment: Because `return` ends the function immediately.

Comment: Even with the fix to the return, this code doesn’t make much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return statement indented too much.

```py
def whence(g, v):
    # Your code here
    lov = []
    count = 0 
    for key, value in g.items(): 
        if v in value:
            lov.append(count)
        count += 1
        print(lov)
    return lov
```

Comment: This answers the question, but if the input keys are not sequential integers starting with zero, then it won't work because of the use of `count`. I don't understand why someone would even create a dict if the keys were just numbers - may as well be a list of lists.

Comment: That's true. The code should use `key` instead of `count`. With this change, the function can handle non-sequential keys as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in one line:

```
def whence(g, v):
    return [key for key, values in g.items() if v in values]
```